# Kelly Criterion, Taylor Expansion and Edward Thorpe

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I was trying to read the following paper by Professor Edward Thorpe on Kelly Criterion:

http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf

On p.22, $n$ independent random variables $X_i, i=1,\cdots,n$ are defined such that

$P(X_i=m/n+s/n^{-1/2})=P(X_i=m/n-s/n^{-1/2})=1/2$ for all $i$

and $$g(f)=E \ln \prod_{i=1}^n (1+(1-f)r+fX_i).$$

Then he claimed that $g(f)$ is equal to (equation (7.1))

$$g(f)=r+f(m-r)-\frac{s^2f^2}{2}+O(n^{-1/2}).$$

Here $m,s$ and $r$ are all constants. I was trying to derive equation 7.1 myself but I couldn't.

I found that

$$g(0)=n\ln (1+r)$$

$$g'(0)=\frac{m-nr}{1+r}$$

and hence the coefficients in the taylor expansion don't match to that of equation 7.1. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: The derivation of $g(0)$ is straight forward, just substitute $f=0$, for $g'(0)$:

I just use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln h(x) = \frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}.$

Comment: Why create a new tag?

Comment: I suspect $r$ became $\frac rn$ (line 29) so your $g(0)$ would be something like $n \log_e(1+\frac{r}{n}) \approx r$ with a similar effect on $g'(0)$

Answer (score 1):

"I was trying to read the following paper..."  - my experience, too. I've come to the conclusion that the equations simply don't make sense. The expression for the maximum, $f^*$, given on line 26, $f^* = (m-r)/s^2$, is false. For example, for $r=0,\ m=.10,\ s=.2$, the formula gives 2.5 times the total wealth in the portfolio as the optimal position size. If one were to lever a portfolio that much, a $60\%$ investment loss would cause it to blow up, and wipe out, not only any and all gains, but the entire initial investment. That is not the mark of an optimal strategy.

Comment: @RiskJarosh:  The expression is not false.  The strategy is "optimal" in that it maximizes the geometric growth rate and the expected logarithm of wealth.  It is without risk only in the sense that risk of ruin is theoretically zero assuming the bet size can be made arbitrarily small.  Nevertheless, recovery from drawdowns with Kelly optimal betting can take an enormously long time.  That is one reason why gamblers suggest "half-Kelly" strategies.  The paper derives the optimal fraction in a complicated way by looking at bets made at discrete points in time and passing to the limit.

Comment: The formula $f^* = (m-r)/s^2$ appears more transparently in solving the problem of optimal portfolio allocation between a risky and a riskless asset assuming a log utility function.  Assuming the risky asset follows a geometric Brownian motion $dS/S = mdt + sdZ$ and the riskless rate of return is $r$, we get the same expression for the optimal weight.  Maximizing log utility is a very aggressive strategy as you observed and maximizing without constraint leads to leverage.

Comment: It doesn't maximize the geometric growth rate because that rate goes to $-\infty$. No strategy that can blow up is optimal. There is no recovery from a blow up, ever. The distribution I mentioned does have positive expectation, so an optimal fraction does exist, but it must be unlevered.

Comment: I am merely addressing the mathematical properties of the very idealized Kelly betting strategy and the analogous optimal portfolio allocation to a risky and riskless asset.  These are well documented in the literature.  Nothing I am saying is applicable to the risk of managing a real portfolio.  Bets and investment allocations can never be arbitrarily small, investment returns are never independent and identically distributed (although gambling outcomes like spin of a wheel or toss of a coin can come close).

Comment: It would be foolish, obviously, to allocate 2.5 times total wealth to the S&P 500 index based on a result based on assuming the index return follows a random process like geometric Brownian motion with constant known volatility and independent returns. Also, these Kelly based strategies are "better" than other strategies only in terms of asymptotic long run behavior.

Comment: Your comments are all spot on, but the abstract model itself is mathematically inconsistent. The thesis that $f^* =(m-r)/s^2$ represents the optimal fraction is wrong for levered portfolios. There are valid methods to discover the optimal fraction given continuous distributions...

Comment: Now I see what is going on. From Line 10 on page 23 of Thorp's paper: "Note further that the investor who follows the policy $f$ must now adjust his investment “instantaneously”.". Making investments at discrete points of time over a lognormal density (which is what I assumed to be the approach) is not the same as continuously adjusting position size over a lognormal diffusion process (which is what Thorp actually did). So, $g_\infty(f^*)$ is correct as derived, but it is completely inapplicable to any actual stock portfolio, and also many that are theoretical.